# How to make an input type=date required using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.2.23 and I would like to make a input type=date required, I have the following code:

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <input id="date" name="date" type="date" required />
    <span ng-show="form.date.$error.required">The date is required!</span>
</form>
```

<kbd>[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/u6W1EGfGIIyBu2sNkUTB?p=preview)</kbd>

The span with the message doesn't appear, why?

---

If input type date are not supported in Angular 1.2.23, is there any good alternative to validate?

Comment: have you tried adding a ng-model? putting your code directly into a fiddle shows the message: http://jsfiddle.net/9yp75kr3/

Comment: I feel worldwide shame...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to bind your input field to a value in your scope using the ngModel directive

Here is an updated plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/orhtCBL295atga5jsT6p?p=preview

```
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <input id="date" name="date" type="date" ng-model="date" required />
    <span ng-show="form.date.$error.required">The date is required!</span>
  </form>
```

Comment: Now, I really feel dumb. Thanks @jcruz, it worked as expected.